# Hadoop:copying csv file to hdfs using flume spool dir, Error: INFO source.SpoolDirectorySource: Spooling Directory Source runner has shutdown

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming, flume-ng

im trying to use flume spool dir to copy csv file to hdfs. as i'm beginner in Hadoop concepts. Please help me out in resolving the below issue

**hdfs directory :    /home/hdfs

flume dir : /etc/flume/**

please find the flume-hwdgteam01.conf file as below

```
# Define a source, a channel, and a sink
hwdgteam01.sources = src1
hwdgteam01.channels = chan1
hwdgteam01.sinks = sink1

# Set the source type to Spooling Directory and set the directory
# location to /home/flume/ingestion/

hwdgteam01.sources.src1.type = spooldir
hwdgteam01.sources.src1.spoolDir = /home/hwdgteam01/nandan/input-data
hwdgteam01.sources.src1.basenameHeader = true

# Configure the channel as simple in-memory queue
hwdgteam01.channels.chan1.type = memory

# Define the HDFS sink and set its path to your target HDFS directory
hwdgteam01.sinks.sink1.type = hdfs
hwdgteam01.sinks.sink1.hdfs.path = /home/datalanding
hwdgteam01.sinks.sink1.hdfs.fileType = DataStream

# Disable rollover functionallity as we want to keep the original files
hwdgteam01.sinks.sink1.rollCount = 0
hwdgteam01.sinks.sink1.rollInterval = 0
hwdgteam01.sinks.sink1.rollSize = 0
hwdgteam01.sinks.sink1.idleTimeout = 0

# Set the files to their original name
hwdgteam01.sinks.sink1.hdfs.filePrefix = %{basename}

# Connect source and sink
hwdgteam01.sources.src1.channels = chan1
hwdgteam01.sinks.sink1.channel = chan1
```

following ways i executed the commands :

/usr/bin/flume-ng agent --conf conf --conf-file /home/hwdgteam01/nandan/config/flume-hwdgteam01.conf -Dflume.root.logger=DEBUG,console --name hwdgteam01

OR

/usr/bin/flume-ng agent -n hwdgteam01 -f /home/hwdgteam01/nandan/config/flume-hwdgteam01.conf

/usr/bin/flume-ng agent -n hwdgteam01 -f /home/hwdgteam01/nandan/config/flume-hwdgteam01.conf

OR

/home/hwdgteam01/nandan/config/flume-ng agent -n hwdgteam01 -f

OR

/home/hwdgteam01/nandan/config/flume-hwdgteam01.conf

but nothing worked out and m getting the following error [flume error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LlDU.png).

please let me know where im going wrong .
thanks for any help